# Regex to match a url and replace with another url

Tags: php, regex

Helo,

I am a regular expression noob, trying to find resources online but the language is so foreign to me. Appreciate if anyone can help to shed some light on this.

Basically, I have successfully able to use dom method to find an image url in "img" tag using getAttribute('src') in a random string.

Example:

```
$string = '<a><img src=http://123.com/123.jpg/></a><img src=http://test.com/test.jpg/>'; //some random string
$url = get_img_url($string) //function of getting a url from a string.
```

Now here comes the challenge. How do I replace $url with another url, say, $url2? And subsequently save to $newstring? I have thought of using preg_replace, but how do I go about having this?

```
$url2 = 'http://example.com/content_image/blogger_1.jpg';
$find = ???                 //find $url i gotten in the function above in $string
$replace = ???              //replace with $url2
$newstring = preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks guys!

Edited:
Appended desired output, thanks Amit Joki!

```
echo $newstring;
```

Result would be:

```
<a><img src=http://example.com/content_image/blogger_1.jpg/></a><img src=http://test.com/test.jpg/>
```

Comment: Show some test cases and how the ouput should be

Comment: basically, i want to replace an existing url "$url" in "$string" (consist of html tags) with another url, say "$url2".

Comment: Are you trying to replace it in the entire document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(<img.+?src=)(.+?)(\s|>)
```

and replace it with:

```
$1http://example.com$3
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zQ7nL8)

I don't know php, but you've to do it as:

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

where `$pattern` is my regex, `$replacement` is my replace string and `$string` is your inputstring.

Comment: Hi Amit, sorry, but I am confused, I am not good in regex. Can you explain how do I apply this? Will this work if $string has more than one url?

Comment: @Architheutus, wait I'll come up with a demo

Comment: Hi amit, what if i just want to match a url, the 2nd url in $string (http://test.com/test.jpg) remain untouched as above?

Comment: nope, in the $string right, i want to replace "http://123.com/123.jpg" only, but not "http://test.com/test.jpg" (these 2 urls could change, so i use $url to denote the one i want to change)

Comment: @Architheutus, then you can easily replace it with str_replace, no need of regex at atll

Comment: thanks Amit, I just realize that as well, sorry for the inconveniences. many thanks for the heads up. It helps me to understand regex better.

Comment: @Architheutus, then you should accept this answer, so the wider community knows that it is useful :)

Comment: Not sure how to accept comments as an answer, but i will just tick the post. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can match the following regex:

`<img src=([^\>]*)>`

and replace with

`<img src=new link>`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/oK7fZ2